# In Ubuntu16.04 with python3.5.2 installed, something wrong with gedit

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gedit

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 x84_64, 
I've installed Anaconda4.2(python3.5.2), then I use this to install gedit.

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
```

I was trying to install some plugins that I use quite frequently and I came into some issues.

```
(gedit:4429): libpeas-WARNING **: Error initializing Python Plugin `Loader: PyGObject initialization failed`
ImportError: could not import gobject (error was: ImportError("No module named 'gi'",))

(gedit:4429): libpeas-WARNING **: Please check the installation of all the Python related packages required by libpeas and try again

(gedit:4429): libpeas-WARNING **: Loader 'python3' is not a valid PeasPluginLoader instance
```

Then I followed some answers to change the plugin file,

```
Loader=python3  ----->  Loader=python
```

While it keeps showing error as :

```
'(gedit:4907): libpeas-WARNING **: The 'python' plugin loader has not been enabled'
```

How can I fix this??
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What does ``python --version`` say?

Comment: Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)

Comment: It sounds like the gedit installer is attempting to use the alias ``python3`` during installation, but you have ``python`` as the alias for Python 3. You could try adding an alias ``python3`` using this command: ``alias python3="python"`` and then running the gedit installer again. This alias will remain until you close the session.

Comment: On a sidenote, ``ImportError: could not import gobject (error was: ImportError("No module named 'gi'",))`` is a common symptom for trying to run a Python 3 project using Python 2.x. But I don't think that is happening here.

Comment: I just tried as you said, but the errors are the same...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running?

```
apt install python3-gi
```

Comment: Yes, I've installed it.